# Enter password in command prompt on fly

Tags: command

I have a problem here.

```
        string strDir = @"cd /d d:\dirc";
        string strCmd = @"gpg --output d:\dirop\outputfile.TXT --decrypt d:\dirip\encfile.enc";  
        string strPass = TheWCF.GetPassphrase(); \\Which will return a string value.

        Process pr;
        ProcessStartInfo args = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");  
        args.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        args.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        args.UseShellExecute = false;
        args.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        pr = Process.Start(args);

        pr.StandardInput.WriteLine(strDir);
        Application.DoEvents();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Application.DoEvents();

        pr.StandardInput.WriteLine(strCmd);
        Application.DoEvents();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Application.DoEvents();
```

Upto here everything is OK but At this point the cmd prompt will asks for passphrase...
How to pass passphrase here from code behind (passphrase we get from another service which i cant hardcode) for example:

```
 string strPassPhrase=TheWCF.GetPassphrase();
```

How to pass this strPassPhrase to command prompt?
Please suggest a way
Thanks in advance

Comment: use echo and the value of variable , strcmd="echo"+strPassPhrase

Answer (score 0):

This may be too obvious, but have you tried

```
pr.StandardInput.WriteLine(strPassPhrase);
```

From the Microsoft MSDN page:

> A Process can read input text from its standard input stream,
>   typically the keyboard. By redirecting the StandardInput stream, you
>   can programmatically specify the input. For example, instead of using
>   keyboard input, you can provide text from the contents of a designated
>   file or output from another application. ref:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx

Actually, it seems like it's exactly what you want... as in this example (slightly modified from the reference linked above):

```
Dim myStreamWriter As StreamWriter = pr.StandardInput

     ' Prompt the user for input text lines to sort.  
     ' Write each line to the StandardInput stream of 
     ' the sort command. 
     Dim inputText As String 
     Dim numLines As Integer = 0
Do
        pr.WriteLine("Enter a line of text (or press the Enter key to stop):")
        inputText = pr.StandardInput.ReadLine()
        If inputText.Length > 0 Then
           numLines += 1
           myStreamWriter.WriteLine(inputText)
        End If 
     Loop While inputText.Length <> 0
```

Comment: Hi Rot, 

Thanks for you reply

I tried in that way too

    pr.StandardInput.WriteLine(strPass);

But still it is asking for password in the command prompt.